# using sqlcipher database on android and ios

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm using sqlcipher db file on flutter.

First, I have built sqlcipher db file on flutter.

And then, I ran it on android.

Insert, query, delete all went well.

I inserted a lot of data into the sqlcipher db.

After that, I copied the sqlcipher db file into iPhone.

However, when I ran the sqlcipher db file on iPhone, the db query didn't seem to recognize the tables in the sqlcipher db.

Especially, it was impossible to select data.

On android, it had no problem.

But, on ios, it had a problem.

I want to know the reason....

I expected it would go well on ios as well.

But it didn't go so

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a link to which package/library you are using. Saying 'things did not go well' isn't useful. Check logs for errors and add those to your question. If there is a github project attached to the library, check the issue tickets for people with similar problems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll show you some of my pubspec.yaml.---------------------------
dependencies:
  sqflite:^2.0.3
  sqflite_sqlcipher:^2.2.1
  sqflite_common:^2.5.0

dependency_overrides:
  sqflite:
     git:
        url:https://www.github.com/davidmartos96/sqflite_sqlcipher.git
       path:sqflite
       ref:fmdb_override